# Roman Numeral to Integer: what is wrong with my code

Tags: java, roman-numerals

So I'm trying to make a converter from roman numerals to integers. What I have so far is this:

```
public int toNumber(String n){
   int number = 0;
   int first = 1;
   int last = 0;      
   String substring = n.substring (last, first);

   while(substring.equals("I")){
            number = number+1;
            last = last +1;
            first=first +1;
        }


   while(substring.equals("V")){
            number = number+5;
            last = last +1;
            first=first +1;
        }
        return number;

}
```

Obviously I only have I and V in right now, but when I make a tester class to try this out, it returns nothing and keeps letting me put in in a new line.

For the record, here is my tester class

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Tester{
    public static void main (String[] args){
        RomanNumeralConverter quantity = new RomanNumeralConverter();
       Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);

       //this is for roman to number  
          System.out.println("input roman numeral");
          String j  = user_input.nextLine(); 
          int g = quantity.toNumber(j);
          System.out.println(g);

    }
}
```

I'm almost entirely certain that it's a logic problem, but I have no idea what and I feel like I've tried everything I can think of

Comment: `while(substring.equals("I"))` ... and where do you change `substring` so this could return `false`? Your program doesn't keep letting you input stuff, it stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: the String class has a charAt(int index) method, that can be used to get a character at a particular location, just so you know.

Comment: I kind of figured that it was stuck in an infinite loop, but how do I get it to return false when  I want it to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is a loop like this:

```
while(substring.equals("I")) {
    number = number+1;
    last = last +1;
    first=first +1;
}
```

If the program enters that loop, it will stuck there, because you're not changing the value of `substring`. Therefore `substring.equals("I")` will always return `true` and the only way to stop that loop is terminating the application.

A better way to convert the entered String could be this:

```
public int toNumber(String n) {
    int number = 0;

    for (char chr : n.toUpperCase().toCharArray()) {
        switch(chr) {
            case 'I': number += 1;
                      break;
            case 'V': number += 5;
                      break;
            default: break;
        }
    }

    return number;
}
```

It converts the provided String to uppercase (`viii` -> `VIII`) to avoid checking both cases of every `char` and converts it into a `char` array. This array will be used in a `foreach` loop that takes every single entry of it and tests it in a `switch` block. Every supported roman numeral has his own `case` there to increment `number` accordingly. Currently it supports `I` and `V` like in your code. Btw, `number += 1` is just a short version of `number = number + 1`.

After that loop, it returns the converted integer value.